# Compare nsurl or string in swift 2

Tags: string, swift2, nsurl

I am comparing two nsurl which are same but if condition is failing

```
        if (url.absoluteString == self.currentPlayer?.currentAssetURL())


values
(lldb) po url.absoluteString
"Optional(https://a.t/y.mp3)"

(lldb) po self.currentPlayer?.currentAssetURL()
▿ Optional("https://a.t/y.mp3")
  - Some : "https://a.t/y.mp3"
```

both urls are same but if condition is failing. 
Please suggest.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The print out of `NSURL` and `NSString` looks the same but the classes are different. `.absoluteString` returns a string

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was optional added inside the string and outside the string.
I fixed it.